# PGFplots Boxplot, using values of median, quartile... outside axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfmath, boxplot

I try to make some boxplots to some given data and use the calculated values (pgfplots did) of the median, quartiles, average,... outside the axis environment.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[utf8,fleqn]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
v
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.8
0.9
1.0 
1.5
 \end{filecontents*}


\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{axis}[
boxplot,
table/y=v,
xmin=0, xmax=1.6, 
ymin=0, ymax=2,
]
    \addplot[fill=orange, thick] table[] {\jobname.csv} 
[above]
node at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{median},1){Median \pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{median}}}
;

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

I can view the values inside the plot, but any attempt to use it outside failed up to now. Any def, xdef, did not work.

Any suggestions?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the place to define the values:

```
    \addplot[fill=orange, thick] table[] {\jobname.csv} 
[above]
node at (boxplot box cs: \boxplotvalue{median},1){Median \pgfmathprintnumber{\boxplotvalue{median}}\xdef\med{\boxplotvalue{median}}\xdef\uq{\boxplotvalue{upper quartile}}\xdef\lq{\boxplotvalue{lower quartile}}\xdef\uw{\boxplotvalue{upper whisker}}\xdef\lw{\boxplotvalue{lower whisker}}\xdef\av{\boxplotvalue{average}}}
;
```